# How to improve code with similar XPath locators c#

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have few elements with similar XPath locators:

```
By.XPath(".//button[contains(text(), 'View Details')]")

By.XPath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Additional Data')]")

By.XPath("By.XPath(".//button[contains(text(), 'Submit')]")
```

.ect
how to create more effective code?
without dublicate `.//button[contains(text()` part

I try use:

```
public string locator = ".//button[contains(text(), '{0}')]";

By.XPath(locator , "View Details")
```

Is it correct way?

Answer (score 0):

I understand the desire to "optimize" things in code but each one of these is a locator for a different element. If you start combining strings, etc. it's going to make the locator harder to read. The saying goes, you write code once and read it ten times so make your code readable. I would leave them as is... but read on for more suggestions.

1. Do you need `contains()` on all of those buttons? If the HTML is

   ```
   <button>View Details</button>
   ```

   then you don't need `contains()`.
2. Do you need the `.` at the start of each XPath? It's only needed if you are searching from another element using an XPath, e.g.

   ```
   IWebElement e = driver.FindElement(...);
   e.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//button")
   ^ search from element 'e'
   ```

   If all you are using it for is

   ```
   driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//button")
   ```

   then you don't need the `.`.